# SQL Server Reshape Result Dimensions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a working stored procedure which makes 11 queries and then returns a 11 x 3 result.

```
Type1                      Amount1              Count1
------------------------- --------------------- --------------------
O                         13769490.24           36
E                         13769490.24           0
C                         13769490.24           165611
GDCB                      11175841.12           162401
GDCA                      2599531.55            3506
PLRO                      1463.49               37
TROOP                     6928001.27            162419
LICS                      6857439.66            159353
CGDP                      0.00                  0
CPP                       6714450.94            62406
NPP                       369.81                37
```

I want to change it to a 1 X 33 result.

```
Type1  Amount1      Count1 Type2 Amount2      Count2 Type3  ....... (ETC)        
----- ------------- ------ ----- ------------ ------ ------
O      13769490.24  36     E     13769490.24  0      C      ....... (ETC)
```

Any ideas on how to reshape this result?  Pivot will not work because I am not using an aggregator.

Comment: Consider reviewing what's your end result should be. this is really make very less sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm too lazy to write the `PIVOT`, but you can use a  `CASE` expression:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Type1)
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT  MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Type1 END) Type1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Amount1 END) Amount1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Count1 END) Count1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Type1 END) Type2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Amount1 END) Amount2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Count1 END) Count2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Type1 END) Type3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Amount1 END) Amount3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Count1 END) Count3,
        /*...... add the rest of the cases here ....*/
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 11 THEN Type1 END) Type11,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 11 THEN Amount1 END) Amount11,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 11 THEN Count1 END) Count11
FROM CTE
```

[**Here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbe49/2) an sqlfiddle with a demo.

And the results are:

```
╔═══════╦══════════╦════════╦═══════╦═════════╦════════╦═══════╦═════════╦════════╦════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ Type1 ║ Amount1  ║ Count1 ║ Type2 ║ Amount2 ║ Count2 ║ Type3 ║ Amount3 ║ Count3 ║ Type11 ║ Amount11 ║ Count11 ║
╠═══════╬══════════╬════════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ C     ║ 13769490 ║ 165611 ║ CGDP  ║       0 ║      0 ║ CPP   ║ 6714450 ║  62406 ║ TROOP  ║  6928001 ║  162419 ║
╚═══════╩══════════╩════════╩═══════╩═════════╩════════╩═══════╩═════════╩════════╩════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

As bad as this sounds, you could attempt using a temp table. As you seem to know all your columns and what they'd be, you'd create a table and then `INSERT` rows from the first query, then `UPDATE` the other columns with results from the second query.

At the end you'll have a single `SELECT` statement from the temp table that would return all your results.

Of course this is a bad idea if the amount of queries might change or the column names might vary.